# Web Parts Chrome Type is not Working

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, view

I am remotely connected to my clients sharepoint server 2010 standard using cisco vpn.
I can see that the announcement list's webpart on our page has Title and Border which shows that chrome type is in effect correctly.
But when my client access the sharepoint site (from their LAN), they say that they cannot see the border for the announcement list's webpart.

When I checked the property of the webpart from my side(using vpn), chrome type was configured correctly to "Title and Border".

What could be the problem? If the chrome type is set, shouldn't it apply to all users using sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a publishing page, ie, a page within the pages library. Then I believe, you need to publish the page after you have checked in for others to view your changes.

If that's not the case, check the browser versions and settings that you and the client is using to view, may be they are different.

Also, if you are using a custom master page, check whether your master page and respective css is checked in and published too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone hid it with custom css?
(+ I guess you pressed ok and save the page after selecting "Title and Border"? Otherwise you'll continue to see it until you stop edit-mode of the page...)